# How to add layout behaviour to Extended Floating Action Button

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

I have an Extended FAB button inside a coordinator layout.

But I couldn't find a way to extend its behaviour so that it hides and shows up on scrolling. Normal FAB button has `FloatingActionButton.Behavior()`.does Extended FAB have these Behaviours? how can we do that?

thanks